# Do visual designers often use existing sketch/Photoshop/illustrator templates or start from scratch

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, sketch-app

I think my workflow is extremely inefficient since Everytime I start a new project for visual design I have to start all over again ...

Seems like I cannot reuse anything between projects. Is this normal? Or do people building a symbol library that they can reuse.

Also for every project I start by searching sketch resources for a template that might be a fit in terms of color combinations and then I start tweaking it.
Is this how one should do it ?

Comment: "visual design" is very broad, could be a bit more specific?

Comment: I meant when doing visual design for mobile applications

Answer (score 3):

I personally tend to use "common assets' *far* more than any template. Common assets meaning, swatches, paragraph, character, object, table, graphic, layer styles, brushes, shapes ... An InDesign library containing commonly used artwork (bursts, banners, buttons, etc). Those sort of things.

I only use what could be called "templates" in a couple areas....

For **InDesign**... a blank document set to the size I need and containing general Paragraphs, Character, Table, Cell, and Object Styles I customarily start with. But I always then alter for each piece. I don't have any "templated" layout which contain any actual artwork though (save maybe page numbers).

For **Illustrator/Photoshop.**. I have nothing... except maybe stored color swatches, brushes, styles, etc. But those are more common resource files than "templates".

I do tend to *not* use Photoshop/Illustrator for layout purposes. If I were to use them to that extent, I'd have the same basic document setups I do for InDesign. Just blank pages set up to size and containing general styles for use - no preexisting art though.

For **web pages/emails**, yes I have templates. Various HTML/CSS pages with layouts for different uses. This is probably the only area where I have set up specific elements with colors, type, sizes, position etc. And then adjust as a project requires. Web page templates are far more about saving time and effort by not requiring me to rewrite markup than about design choices.

(I don't really do UI design.. but if I did, I'd treat it a lot like web design... and I'd have UI templates with formatted art for buttons, etc).

---

For me existing artwork templates are a road block. They set my creative thinking down a specific path. I then must force myself to veer off that path consciously. By starting with a blank slate, I force myself to be more creative rather than forcing myself just the be "different" than the last time.

I do tend to sketch on a small, crappy, wire-bound, notepad I keep on my desk. It's just faster to scribble by hand than to use applications for exploring ideas. (Except web design.. wireframes are faster.)

Comment: Exactly this. Reusable resources/assets are a must but actual *templates* are really bad for creativity; I've attempted it a few times and it's always done more harm than good.

Comment: (except your last sentence... I still find wireframing web stuff on paper much quicker and easier)

Comment: The problem I have with paper and wireframing is that blocks can subconsciously be sized to fit the idea... rather than the idea using set sizes. By using applications all the "boxes" remain the same size so the jigsaw pieces aren't distorted to fit a layout :)

Comment: Sure, there's definitely a ton of benefits to doing it digitally I just find paper a hell of a lot quicker. I pretty much exclusively use grid paper too so I'm pretty good with sizing things

Comment: To each his (or her) own :)

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. Here you don't mention Sketch. Is there a similar workflow for sketch that you follow?

Also, how much time did it create for you to create the common assets? Months, Years or Days? 

Is there a set of common assets for Sketch, that I can get started with?

Comment: @user855 I don't use Sketch.. I have Adobe products negating any need for Sketch. I'd be happy to explore Sketch.. but to date.. I've seen no compelling thing Sketch does which can't be done in any of the Adobe apps I already pay for.